# Dock, exposé and mission control crashed / quit

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I'm stuck on a space and have no access to the dock, exposé or mission control. Consequently, I have no access to any of my apps on other spaces. I tried running: `killall Dock` (with and without sudo), but it returns `No matching processes belonging to you were found`.

Is there anyway I can re-launch the crashed dock (so I can save my work) without having to reboot?

Comment: Can you still access Spotlight to run Terminal? Or login from another machine via ssh/telnet?

Comment: Yep I can get to Terminal (where I tried killing the dock). I'm wondering if there's a way to launch the dock program, but I've no idea where it is located (and my Googling was fruitless!).